# How to iterate over server data in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to iterate over this data from server:

```json
{ tHead: {
       cellList: [
        {content: "commission"}, 
        {content: "01"}
                 ]
         }, 
  tBody: {
       cellList:[
        {content: "body content"}, 
        {content: "09"}
                ]
         }
}
```

I tried this but it gives me error:

```html
<th *ngFor="let data of serverData.tHead.CellList">{{data.content}}</th>
```

Any ideas on how to do it?

- How would i set my variable `serverData` ? With `serverData: myPropertyInterface[]` or like this `serverData: myProperty = {} as myPropertyInterface`?

Comment: It's giving you an error because you have a typo, it should be `serverData.tHead.cellList` not `serverData.tHead.CellList`

Comment: Sorry i typed it wrong here, i'll change that on my question right know!

Comment: Okay i changed the code as you said i had the interface property miss typed like this `CellList` changed to `cellList` but it still gives me `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cellList')`

Comment: Your cellList is another array, so you would have to also iterate over it to get content of each object in that array.

Comment: you might use like it so it doesn't get failed before getting data from server serverData?.tHead?.cellList

Comment: I managed to read the table head data from the server (the problem was that the API call was too slow so the table wasn't able to use any data because it wasn't still there. Now the problem relies on the table body where i looped through the `tBody` and also through the `cellList` of each single `tBody` (which is a row) but i still get the same message on the console. Anyway thanks for replying you made my day and saved me from a possible work panic!